# I'm asking because I don't know how to change the Linux post command into Retrofit 2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I can't find it even after searching, so I'm asking

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Basic a2V5OjRlYzg4MDBiOWIwMGRjOTBkODc3NGYwMDk2YTMzNmNl" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d "{\"request\": {\"query\": \"Hello\"}}"\
https://builder.pingpong.us/api/builder/5ebe0072e4b0e921afb5c210/integration/v0.2/custom/{sessionId}
```

​I'm trying to apply this by changing it to Kotlin retrofit2, but I can't figure it out.

​Especially
`-d "{\"request\": {\"query\": \"Hello\"}}"\`
this part

```
interface RetrofitServic {

@POST("2233551")
@Headers("Authorization: Basic Basic a2V5OjRlYzg4MDBiOWIwMGRjOTBkODc3NGYwMDk2YTMzNmNl",
"Content-Type:application/json")
fun postInfo()

}
```

I've made it this far, but I don't know what happened after that, but if you know, please reply

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the required outcome is adding a body to the POST request. In this case, the approach I usually use is to create an argument model and pass it as a parameter of a function, like this:

The model

```
data class PostInfoArg(val request: RequestArg)
data class RequestArg(val query: String)
```

The function:

```
@POST("2233551")
@Headers("Authorization: Basic Basic a2V5OjRlYzg4MDBiOWIwMGRjOTBkODc3NGYwMDk2YTMzNmNl",
"Content-Type:application/json")
fun postInfo(@Body arg: PostInfoArg)
```

And then you can call it like that:

```
myService.postInfo(PostInfoArg(RequestArg("hello")))
```

Btw, in this case, you don't need a Content-Type header, it will be applied automatically, but don't forget to apply a converter:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("your url")
            .create()
```

and it would require a dependency on the converter in your module-specific build.gradle(.kts):

```
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion")
```